# Why this react button is not changing the div text color when pressed?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

My question is why this button is not changing the div text color to green when pressed?

Here's the code, I hope it will be useful for you to help me with this doubt:

```
import React from 'react';
import hola from './hola.css'

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { color: props.color };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ color: this.state.color }}> Hello World! </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { color: 'red' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child color={this.state.color} />
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ color: 'green'})}>
          Change Color
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Constructor runs only once. You should not save props in state.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor runs once and you copy its initial value into the state, that never changes.
You have two options here:

1. Move the button into the component, and make it set the component's own state:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ color: this.state.color }}> Hello World! </div>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ color: 'green'})}>
        Change Color
      </button>
  )
}
```

2. Use the props directly:

```js
<div style={{ color: this.props.color }}> Hello World! </div>
```